# Installation of MS SQL Database 2005 on Windows XP Home Sp3 fails with no specific error

Tags: installation, database

I am trying to install MS SQL Database 2005 on Windows XP Home SP3. It fails giving no reason ("Database failed to install"), then exits. I had already installed MS SQL Database Express Edition 2008 during 2005 setup. But when I removed 2008 one and tried to install 2005 afterwards it still failed with same error.

The error happens when I am trying to install Dragon Age Toolset or Visual 2008 Pro edition.

I do not known which else informations may be valuable as I never before encountered problems with installing MS database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 and other Microsoft mastodons are very hard to completely uninstall.

To make sure you have totally uninstalled see :
[How to uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955499)
[SQL Server 2008 Install Nightmare](http://www.intellitechture.com/SQL-Server-2008-Install-Nightmare/)

Then try again to install SQLDatabase 2005.
If this doesn't work, then unfortunately the only solution may be to reinstall Windows from scratch.

Comment: I made clear reinstall of Windows and now everything works

Answer (score 0):

If its installing in unattended mode (which I think it is during  a VS install) try looking in %temp%\sqlsetup*.log *see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143702.aspx

Without the logs it's impossible to diagnose what is going wrong.

You may also try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967, which gives instructions on manually removing SQL Server 2005 in preparation for a reinstall.

Comment: There are no logs, the only file with "SQL" in name in temps is "SQL168.mft" which contain text errors similar to "Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Setup was unable to install on your computer."/"Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Setup has encountered a problem and will end."

The entire file is available here: http://nopaste.gamedev.pl/?id=6091

Comment: Open the cab file mentioned in the last line of the SQL 168.mft file. You should find the logs your looking for in there.